# How to depoly akka in distributed system, to achieve High Availability?

Tags: web, akka, distributed, high-availability, failover

I am a newbie in Akka. But I have been working in web project for several years.
Previously, We user "ngix+ tomcat cluster" plan, once one of the tomcat server crash(physically machine crash), the other members of the tomcat cluster would take over the request destined to the failed server. And we achieve the High Availability through this.
    In our new web project, we plan to use akka to achieve the fault tolerance and scalability. Here is one server to be master actor, whose jobs is to dispatch the request messages from outside to the child actors. The child actors may be distributed locally or remotely. Once any one of the child actor failed, the master actor would fix it. 
    My question is, once the master actor failed(maybe the machine crashs), how should I achieve the High Availability in this cases? If the machine crash, where the master actor resides, we have to restart the machine manually. And in this period ,the service has to be stop for a while. It is unacceptable for us.
    Could anyone tell me, how should I do to solve this issues?

Comment: Did you get the solution ..?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use an external load balancer. For example you can report all addresses of your Akka cluster nodes to middle-tier of your web app (and cache them there for some time) and load balance requests from your middle-tier to your Akka backend (for example, pick random cluster node every time).

If your Akka backend reqiures some kind of single point of resource acquisition for your child actors, you can try to use a [Cluster Singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html) as a Master actor. In this case all of cluster nodes should send client requests to the Cluster Singleton and Cluster Singleton then can distribute tasks between all cluster nodes in a some particular way.